# validation of input text field in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, form-submit

```
<script type='text/javascript'>   
function required()  
{
    var empt = document.forms["form1"]["Name"].value; 
    if (empt == "")  
    {  
        alert("Please input a Value");  
        return false;  
    }  
}  
</script> 

<form name="form1" method="" action="">
<input type="text" name="name" value="Name"/><br />
<input type="text" name="address line1" value="Address Line 1"/><br />
```

I have more than one input text field, each having their default value. Before I submit the form I have to verify whether all fields are filled. So far i got the javascript to check for null since different text boxes have different default value. How can I write a javascript to verify that user has entered data? I mean, the script must identify that input data is other than default and null.

Comment: You can use HTML5 validations. That is very simple and you can customize your messages also. No need any javascript or jquery methods for client side validations now. You can check this [link](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/03/13/html5-form-validation.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not using jQuery then I would simply write a validation method that you can be fired when the form is submitted. The method can validate the text fields to make sure that they are not empty or the default value. The method will return a bool value and if it is false you can fire off your alert and assign classes to highlight the fields that did not pass validation.

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" method="" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
<input type="text" name="name" value="Name"/><br />
<input type="text" name="addressLine01" value="Address Line 1"/><br />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm(form) {

    var nameField = form.name;
    var addressLine01 = form.addressLine01;

    if (isNotEmpty(nameField)) {
        if(isNotEmpty(addressLine01)) {
            return true;
        {
    {
    return false;
}

function isNotEmpty(field) {

    var fieldData = field.value;

    if (fieldData.length == 0 || fieldData == "" || fieldData == fieldData) {

        field.className = "FieldError"; //Classs to highlight error
        alert("Please correct the errors in order to continue.");
        return false;
    } else {

        field.className = "FieldOk"; //Resets field back to default
        return true; //Submits form
    }
}
```

The validateForm method assigns the elements you want to validate and then in this case calls the isNotEmpty method to validate if the field is empty or has not been changed from the default value. it continuously calls the inNotEmpty method until it returns a value of true or if the conditional fails for that field it will return false.

Give this a shot and let me know if it helps or if you have any questions. of course you can write additional custom methods to validate numbers only, email address, valid URL, etc.

If you use jQuery at all I would look into trying out the jQuery Validation plug-in. I have been using it for my last few projects and it is pretty nice. Check it out if you get a chance. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: thanks for your reply, your approach is straight forward but somehow i couldn't able to get "FieldOk" even after filling all text boxes,it shows "please correct the errors in order to continue".

Comment: Hey, sorry it took a while to get back to you... I did not include the `'FieldOk'` and `'FieldError'` CSS classes in the example. You can create a set and then set the values of the text and field colors to change to red when there is an error and then set it back to the defaults when the field validates.

Comment: i just noticed the reason why i was getting the error alert, the fieldData is compared with fieldData which is obviously true always instead i need a function to verify that entered field is not the default value in text input.

Comment: Oh, my bad... Well, if you want it to throw the error if the user leaves in the default field values and clicks submit. If the default value is ad always will be "Name". Try and change: `fieldData == fieldData` to `fieldData == "Name"`

Comment: yeah i made those changes,which requires seperate function for each fields,thanks for providing the basic understanding which kept me going.

Answer (score 3):

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="name" /> <br />
    <span id="nameErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
    <!-- ... all your other stuff ... -->
</form>
  <p>
    1.word should be atleast 5 letter<br>
    2.No space should be encountered<br>
    3.No numbers and special characters allowed<br>
    4.letters can be repeated upto 3(eg: aa is allowed aaa is not allowed)
  </p>
  <button id="validateTestButton" value="Validate now" onclick="validateForm();">Validate now</button>


validateForm = function () {
    return checkName();
}

function checkName() {
    var x = document.myForm;
    var input = x.name.value;
    var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById('nameErrMsg');
    if (input.length < 5) {
        errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            'Please enter a name with at least 5 letters';
        return false;
    } else if (!(/^\S{3,}$/.test(input))) {
        errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            'Name cannot contain whitespace';
        return false;
    }else if(!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(input)))
    {
        errMsgHolder.innerHTML=
                'Only alphabets allowed'
    }
    else if(!(/^(?:(\w)(?!\1\1))+$/.test(input)))
    {
        errMsgHolder.innerHTML=
                'per 3 alphabets allowed'
    }
    else {
        errMsgHolder.innerHTML = '';
        return undefined;
    }       

}

.error {
color: #E00000;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Validation</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var radiotags = document.getElementsByName("gender");
            var compareValidator = ['compare'];
            var formtag = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
            function validation(){
                for(var i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
                    var tagid = tags[i].id;
                    var tagval = tags[i].value;
                    var tagtit = tags[i].title;
                    var tagclass = tags[i].className;
                    //Validation for Textbox Start
                    if(tags[i].type == "text"){
                        if(tagval == "" || tagval == null){
                            var lbl = $(tags[i]).prev().text();
                            lbl = lbl.replace(/ : /g,'')
                            //alert("Please Enter "+lbl);
                            $(".span"+tagid).remove();
                            $("#"+tagid).after("<span style='color:red;' class='span"+tagid+"'>Please Enter "+lbl+"</span>");
                            $("#"+tagid).focus();
                            //return false;
                        }
                        else if(tagval != "" || tagval != null){
                            $(".span"+tagid).remove();
                        }
                        //Validation for compare text in two text boxes Start
                        //put two tags with same class name and put class name in compareValidator.
                        for(var j=0;j<compareValidator.length;j++){
                            if((tagval != "") && (tagclass.indexOf(compareValidator[j]) != -1)){
                                if(($('.'+compareValidator[j]).first().val()) != ($('.'+compareValidator[j]).last().val())){
                                    $("."+compareValidator[j]+":last").after("<span style='color:red;' class='span"+tagid+"'>Invalid Text</span>");
                                    $("span").prev("span").remove();
                                    $("."+compareValidator[j]+":last").focus();
                                    //return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //Validation for compare text in two text boxes End
                        //Validation for Email Start
                        if((tagval != "") && (tagclass.indexOf('email') != -1)){
                        //enter class = email where you want to use email validator
                            var reg = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/
                            if (reg.test(tagval)){
                                $(".span"+tagid).remove();
                                return true; 
                            }
                            else{
                                $(".span"+tagid).remove();
                                $("#"+tagid).after("<span style='color:red;' class='span"+tagid+"'>Email is Invalid</span>");
                                $("#"+tagid).focus();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        //Validation for Email End
                    }
                    //Validation for Textbox End
                    //Validation for Radio Start
                    else if(tags[i].type == "radio"){
                    //enter class = gender where you want to use gender validator
                        if((radiotags[0].checked == false) && (radiotags[1].checked == false)){
                            $(".span"+tagid).remove();
                            //$("#"+tagid").after("<span style='color:red;' class='span"+tagid+"'>Please Select Your Gender </span>");
                            $(".gender:last").next().after("<span style='color:red;' class='span"+tagid+"'> Please Select Your Gender</span>");
                            $("#"+tagid).focus();
                            i += 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            $(".span"+tagid).remove();
                        }
                    }
                    //Validation for Radio End              
                    else{

                    }
                }
                //return false;
            }
            function Validate(){
               if(!validation()){
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            function onloadevents(){
                tags[tags.length -1].onclick = function(){
                    //return Validate();
                }
                for(var j=0;j<formtag.length;j++){
                    formtag[j].onsubmit = function(){
                        return Validate();
                    }
                }
                for(var i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
                    var tagid = tags[i].id;
                    var tagval = tags[i].value;
                    var tagtit = tags[i].title;
                    var tagclass = tags[i].className;
                    if((tags[i].type == "text") && (tagclass.indexOf('numeric') != -1)){
                        //enter class = numeric where you want to use numeric validator
                        document.getElementById(tagid).onkeypress = function(){
                            numeric(event);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            function numeric(event){
                var KeyBoardCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode; 
                if (KeyBoardCode > 31 && (KeyBoardCode < 48 || KeyBoardCode > 57)){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(".spannum").remove();
                    //$(".numeric").after("<span class='spannum'>Numeric Keys Please</span>");
                    //$(".numeric").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                    $(".spannum").remove();
                    return true;
            }
            if (document.addEventListener) {
              document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onloadevents, false);
            }
            //window.onload = onloadevents;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <label for="fname">Test 1 : </label><input type="text" title="Test 1" id="fname" class="form1"><br>
            <label for="fname1">Test 2 : </label><input type="text" title="Test 2" id="fname1" class="form1 compare"><br>
            <label for="fname2">Test 3 : </label><input type="text" title="Test 3" id="fname2" class="form1 compare"><br>
            <label for="gender">Gender : </label>
            <input type="radio" title="Male" id="fname3" class="gender" name="gender" value="Male"><label for="gender">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" title="Female" id="fname4" class="gender" name="gender" value="Female"><label for="gender">Female</label><br>
            <label for="fname5">Mobile : </label><input type="text" title="Mobile" id="fname5" class="numeric"><br>
            <label for="fname6">Email : </label><input type="text" title="Email" id="fname6" class="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasValue( val ) { // Return true if text input is valid/ not-empty
    return val.replace(/\s+/, '').length; // boolean
}
```

For multiple elements you can pass inside your input elements loop their value into that function argument.

If a user inserted one or more spaces, thanks to the regex `s+` the function will return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre><form name="myform" action="saveNew" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text"   id="name"   name="name" /> 
<input type="submit"/>
</form></pre>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myform");
    frmvalidator.EnableFocusOnError(false); 
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether(); 
    frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Plese Enter Name"); 

</script>




before using above code you have to add the gen_validatorv31.js js file
```

Answer (score 0):

For flexibility and other places you might want to validated. You can use the following function.

```
`function validateOnlyTextField(element) {
    var str = element.value;
    if(!(/^[a-zA-Z, ]+$/.test(str))){
        // console.log('String contain number characters');
        str = str.substr(0,  str.length -1);
        element.value = str;
    }
}`
```

Then on your html section use the following event.

`<input type="text" id="names" onkeyup="validateOnlyTextField(this)" />`

You can always reuse the function.